# $http set header bug - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, rest

I am having an issue with setting headers to send requests to spring mvc. Below is my code to set headers yet I am still getting this error.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/orgchart/app/json/depts 403 (Forbidden) angular.js:7978
OPTIONS http://localhost/orgchart/app/json/depts No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header  is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. angular.js:7978
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/orgchart/app/json/depts. No 'Access-Control-  Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The angular code i have is below, any ideas?

```
orgChartApp.factory('Depts', function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.put = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With'
    };
    var departmentService = {
        putDepartment: function(dept) {
            var promise = $http.put('http://localhost/orgchart/app/json/depts', {
                name: dept.name,
                parentDepartmentId: dept.parentDepartment.id,
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return departmentService;
});
```

Comment: These headers need to be on the server not the client.  You cannot configure CORS client-side for obvious reasons.

Comment: I do have CORS filter setup and working on Spring MVC backend though and it works for get

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that on this call `http://localhost/orgchart/app/json/depts` the server is not returning CORS headers: `Access-Control-  Allow-Origin`.  You should proxy the request with fiddler (or call directly through Postman) and see what the server returns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after messing with fiddler, there is in fact something wrong with my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, first of all my server end point was not returning a ResponseBody so that was a big issue if I was expecting any return values.

Secondly, I send in individual params, and made sure to add an header for my back-end like so.

```
    putDepartment: function(dept) {
        var promise = $http({
            url: 'http://localhost/orgchart/app/json/dept/' + dept.id,
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {
                    name: dept.name,
                    parentDepartmentId: dept.parentDepartment.id
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.data.depts;
            });
            return promise;
    }
```